# Can I set my bashrc to echo $? after a particular command?

Tags: bash, alias, echo

I'm familiar with setting simple aliases in my .bashrc, and think it might be capable of doing what I want, but not quite sure how to do it.  The desire: always echo $? after a particular program finishes executing.  The particular program I want to run this after prints out fairly awkward STDERR messages that look at first glance like an error even upon success.  I always echo $? after as a first check before I actually read the stuff, but at least a quarter of the time mistype and lose the echo opportunity.  What I'd like to do is set an alias so that when I type

```
$ foo --option [argument]
```

It actually does

```
$ foo --option [argument]

working blah blah blah

$ echo $?
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a function:

```
foo () {
    command foo "$@"
    echo "$?"
}
```

This will just execute the `foo` command with any arguments provided and then echo the exit status afterward.

You may also want to have the `foo` *function* return with the same exit status as the `foo` *command* with:

```
foo() {
  local ret
  command foo "$@"
  ret="$?"
  echo "$ret"
  return "$ret"
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!